# Scala sort list based on second attribute and then first

Tags: list, scala, sorting, tuples

I wish to sort a list containing (word, word.length) first based on length and then words alphabetically. So given: `"I am a girl"` the output should be `a:1, I:1, am:2, girl:4`
I have the following piece of code which works but not for all examples

```
val lengths = words.map(x => x.length)
val wordPairs = words.zip(lengths).toList
val mapwords = wordPairs.sort (_._2 < _._2).sortBy(_._1)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can sort by tuple:

```
scala>  val words = "I am a girl".split(" ")
words: Array[java.lang.String] = Array(I, am, a, girl)

scala>  words.sortBy(w => w.length -> w)
res0: Array[java.lang.String] = Array(I, a, am, girl)

scala>  words.sortBy(w => w.length -> w.toLowerCase)
res1: Array[java.lang.String] = Array(a, I, am, girl)
```

Comment: to get the ouput from the above you add a map function `val output:Array[String] = words.sortBy(w => w.length -> w.toLowerCase) map {x => x + ":" + x.length }`

Comment: +1, you learn something everyday. After looking it up in the docs, it works because the `Ordering` object provides lexicographic ordering for tuples (see implicits `Ordering.Tuple*`)

Answer (score -2):

U can do that in one line:

```
 "I am a girl".toLowerCase.split(" ").map(x => (x,x.length)).sortWith { (x: (String,Int), y: (String,Int)) => x._1 < y._1 }
```

or in two lines:

```
 val wordPairs = "I am a girl".split(" ").map(x => (x,x.length))
 val result = wordPairs.toLowerCase.sortWith { (x: (String,Int), y: (String,Int)) => x._1 < y._1 }
```

Comment: You are only sorting by length, not by length + alphabetic order